# IronPython - Error in URL request

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, python-requests

When using IronPython I make a URL request to get an XML (with python-requests), in the VisualStudio's console I get the following error:

```
failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.3 ()'
```

What does this mean? How can i fix it?

This is the Python code that causes the problem:

```
def __xml_retrieve(self, query_string):
    """ Handles MB speed limits """
    attempt = 0
    while attempt <= self.max_attempts:
        attempt += 1
        # raises connectionerror; still not managed
        try:                
            r = requests.get(query_string)
        except Exception as exc:
            print exc.message 
        if r.status_code == 503:
            time.sleep(self.speed_limit_pause)
        elif r.status_code == 200:
            return r.content
    return
```

The problem born when I call request.get(query_string). This is the requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/.

Comment: Could you a) provide the full stack trace, b) provide some representative code of what is causing the exception?

Comment: How can I print the full stack trace? Now I add the code in the question.

Comment: The full stack trace is what should be printed in VisualStudio's console. `failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.3 ()'` sounds like only part of the stack trace.

Comment: So this seems to be from the [`platform.py`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/platform.py#l1384) module that we use to construct User-Agent strings. Judging by bugs.python.org this [should have been fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue6388). I'll email the maintainer of the module to see if he has any insight.

Comment: Could you also provide `repr(sys.version)`? Also, if you have a chance, could you try running this file? http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/test/test_platform.py I might file a bug report on bugs.python.org so if you're interested in following this you can check there.

Comment: Now I try to run this file: http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/platform.py#l1384. In bugs.python.org they said that the problem would be fixed in version 2.7, but I use the 2.7.

Comment: Could you post `repr(sys.version)` please? I really want to help you fix this including helping python fix this (since this seems to be an issue with python).

Comment: And this is the bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue17994

Comment: If I print the repr(sys.version) the Console says: '2.7.3 ()'. I have to run also the "platform.py"?

Comment: Sorry if I reply now, but my computer crashed and I had to reinstall everything as before in another PC.

Comment: I run also "platform.py" and it returns "failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.3 ()'"

Comment: I also print the full stack trace with `traceback.print_stack()` and the Console returns `None`.